# Safe way to send session based data to SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I know the reason why SignalR is not good to access Session, but can you you guys explain to me the best way to sending sensitive data to SignalR Hub.

here is my problem.

I developing website with a chat feature (xmpp based), chat client (agsxmpp) stayed on the server side on SignalR hub. the problem is every time the page loaded I should send username/password (encrypted) to the SignalR hub to login to the chat client or if it is already login it should make sure the current connected client will getting a correct chat client connection.

even the username/password is encrypted still I am not satisfy to do that. Im not sure what i am doing is correct, please share your knowledge about this or if there are better way to do that I am open for advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just posted a gist on how to use readonly sessions with SignalR. https://gist.github.com/4692934

Comment: I would like to do the same however I don't see ".Request" method ??

Comment: I'd like to say that this was useful, but it did not work for me. Seession was always null. It seems that others had this issue as well. Any thoughts?